# how update operation done in B-tree technique?

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree

As we know, the tree index is the most well-known indexing technique that is used in database systems and file systems. I need to know if there is an update operation in the B-tree technique because all websites talk about insert, delete or search operations. The picture I attached has a question that calcifies what I am looking for.

[Question about balanced trees and updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMrk9.jpg)

> Balanced tree is one of the data access techniques in database. How does it work? How
> data can be inserted in? How data can be deleted from it; how data can be updated? And
> how data can be reviewed? By giving an example explain all of them.

Comment: An update is done by delete (old) and insert (new).  There isn't anything quicker, in general — the entry may need to be moved quite a lot within the B-Tree if the indexed value has changed quite a lot.

Comment: Note that the image is simply text – you should copy the text into the question and mark it as a quote (use a `>` symbol at the start of the first quoted line), and probably due credit (a link to where it is copied from, for example).